# How to tell how much memory is available to a single process in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, redis

I have a Linux server dedicated to Redis. Redis is *supposed* to take up almost all RAM to itself. I am worried that Linux may impose a limit on memory consumption for Redis.

The question is this: how to determine exactly how much RAM one single process can possibly take up without the OS preventing it from doing so?

The information on the Internet is contradictory. There are overcommit_ratio, ulimit and lots of other things that may affect the correct answer. And 99% of all information is focused on limiting memory of process to a small amount with scarce resources. Whereas I am interested in ensuring that my important huge process does smoothly use all the vast RAM that I am going to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, your redis process should get as much memory as it's available on the system (+ swap if any).

Redis docs (https://redis.io/topics/admin) suggest setting overcommit to 1 (never check) which might be beneficial for it being able to allocate large portion of virtual memory address space without actually using it all.
Of course, it might end up using too much memory and being killed by oom-killer (operating system) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207697/redis-process-was-killed-by-os-is-there-a-bug

Comment: It seems I was under wrong impression that default `overcommit_ratio=50` will let me use only half of what I have given I got no swap. But it seems it works only with `overcommit_memory=2`